# Cannot destructure property trouble in enzyme?

Tags: reactjs, enzyme

While I'm trying to make a test

```
import React from "react";
import {EventsLoadingContext} from "../../../src/components/data-admin/context/EventsLoadingContext";
import DataAdmin from "../../../src/components/data-admin/DataAdmin";
import { configure, mount, shallow } from "enzyme";
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';

configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });

it("should render DataAdmin component", () => {
    const component = shallow(<DataAdmin />, {context: EventsLoadingContext});
    const dataTable = component.find(".table-container");
    expect(dataTable.length).toBe(1);
});
```

and have a trouble like that:
[image]

In the context component I have:

```
export const EventsLoadingContext = createContext();

export const WithEventsLoadingContext = ({children}) => {
  const [backendEvents, setBackendEvents] = useState([]);
  const [integrationEvents, setIntegrationEvents] = useState([]);
  const [allEvents, setAllEvents] = useState([]);

// ...

  const value = {
    preparedEvents,
    dropdownItems,
    dropdownClicked, setDropdownClicked,
    loading,
    updatedChanges, setUpdatedChanges
  };

  return (
    <EventsLoadingContext.Provider value = {value}>
        {children}
    </EventsLoadingContext.Provider>
  )
};
```

And in the DataAdmin component I have:

```
const DataAdmin = () => {
  const {
    preparedEvents, 
    dropdownItems,
    dropdownClicked, setDropdownClicked,
    loading,
    updatedChanges, setUpdatedChanges
  } = useContext(EventsLoadingContext);
```

and so on.
So how could I fix that?
So how could I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you should pass the `EventsLoadingContext` context in `options` parameter for `shallow` method. See [shallow documentation](https://enzymejs.github.io/enzyme/docs/api/shallow.html#shallownode-options--shallowwrapper).

Comment: tried that const component = shallow(<DataAdmin />, {context: EventsLoadingContext}); unfortunately that doesn't work